# How can I use the key combination Ctrl + Enter in the AS3 Standalone Flash Player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I did a little test that would black out the screen if key combination `Ctrl + Enter` was pressed:

```
private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.ctrlKey == true && e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
        ColorTransformer.transformColor(screen, new Color(Color.Black));
    }
}
```

Combinations of `Ctrl` and other keys work well.

**UPDATE**

My IDE is FlashDevelop 5.0.0. And the project works well in a browser. I also ran it in the Flash Player (15 Debugger) and it didn't work so I think it's because of the Flash Player.

Comment: Possibly because Ctrl+Enter is the keyboard shortcut for Control > Test Movie.

Comment: I recall there was a parameter to Flash debugger player to disable interception of Flash CS shortcuts, can't find it yet though :(

Comment: Correction to my previous comment - it's Control > Test Movie, except when focus is on the Test Movie window in which case it's View > Simulate Download.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, it is in fact possible, the code you've posted works correctly.

As pointed out in the comments, this issue is that the standalone Flash Player intercepts certain key combinations for it's own keyboard shortcuts (ctr+enter is to play the movie).

There are two solutions I know of to solve your issue:

1. Use an fscommand in standalone flash player to trap those shortcut keys:

   ```
   flash.system.fscommand("trapallkeys","true");
   ```
2. Use the more robust Adobe Air platform instead (if you're not keen on air, you can export an AIR project as a standalone .exe if you add the appropriate flag in the call to adt. (`-target bundle`).  When using an AIR FlashDevelop template, you can change this line in `bat/packager.bat`:

   ```
   call adt -package %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% %OUTPUT% %APP_XML% %FILE_OR_DIR%
   ```

   To:

   ```
   call adt -package %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% -target bundle %OUTPUT% %APP_XML% %FILE_OR_DIR%
   ```

   Then you will get a folder (in the air directory) with an .exe in it (windows) that doesn't require anything installed on the user's machine.

Comment: Did this adequately answer your question?  If so please accept the answer, if not, consider commenting with what is or isn't working